# Use same output asset for 2 job tasks in Azure Media Services

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-media-services

I am using Windows Azure Media Services for video manipulation after upload.  My basic workflow involves uploading the file to an WAMS asset, create a job, create 2 tasks - the first creates thumbnails from the video and the second encodes it to HTML5.  Currently, everything is working great however I am forced to create 2 different output asset containers for the individual tasks.  Once the job completes, I then copy over the files (thumbnails) to the video asset, and delete the thumbnail asset so all resulting files are in the same asset.

This is working, but feels hacky and comes with some overhead of copying over the files, then deleting the unnecessary asset.  Is there a way I can tell the encoding task to use the output asset from the thumbnail task?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.
This is by design and I'd be interested in knowing why your use case requires the .jpg's to be in the same container as your videos.

Comment: I suppose I dont have a great answer, more or less I feel like the jpg's are part of the video asset just as much the .xml, .ism, and .mp4 files are part of the video asset.  In my app, I'm persisting the asset id in my db and use that for reference, I guess I could change my design to store both the "video asset id" and "jpeg's asset id" as 2 columns but again I feel they should be in the same container.  Any reason why they should be separated into their separate assets?

Comment: Or better asked, any reason why this is by design and not convention, without even given the option to specify an existing asset?

Comment: We went down this road because often the security is different around various asset types.  We consider the jps, trailer, and movie to have different streaming needs and didn't want to couple them all together.
Your original question was about merging or re-using output assets, that's not possible.
However, you can use a custom encode profile to do this.  I will reach out to a colleague to provide details to this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following instead.

1. Start with your desired encoding Preset
2. You can get the XML for that preset via downloading the sample code from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=253275, and browsing to the WAMEPresetFiles subfolder
3. Edit the Preset as follows:

   `<`MediaFile ...
           ThumbnailTime="00:00:00"
           ThumbnailMode="BestFrame"
           ThumbnailJpegCompression="95"
           ThumbnailCodec="Jpeg"
           ThumbnailSize="100%, 100%"
           ThumbnailEmbed="False">
4. The above instructs the encoder to choose the appropriate frame on the video timeline (ThumbnailMode=”BestFrame”), and create a JPEG image at the same resolution as the input video. You can tweak the above settings further – see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn554337.aspx for the full list
5. Save the resulting preset XML to a suitable file, say “EncodeWithImage.xml”
6. Use the following snippet to submit the encode Task:

   ```
       string inputPresetFile = @"C:\TEMP\EncodeWithImage.xml";
       string presetName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputPresetFile);
       IAsset asset = ???; // This is the input Asset for the Task

       IJob job = _context.Jobs.Create("Encode Job for " + asset.Name + ", encoded using " +  presetName);
       Console.WriteLine("Encode Job for " + asset.Name + ", encoded using " + presetName);
       // Get a media processor reference, and pass to it the name of the processor to use for the specific task.
       IMediaProcessor processor = GetLatestMediaProcessorByName("Windows Azure Media Encoder");
       Console.WriteLine("Got MP " + processor.Name + ", ID : " + processor.Id + ", version: " + processor.Version);

       // Read the configuration data into a string. 
       string configuration = File.ReadAllText(inputPresetFile);

       // Create a task with the encoding details, using a string preset.
       ITask task = job.Tasks.AddNew("Encode Task for " + asset.Name + ", encoded using " + presetName, processor, configuration,
           Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.TaskOptions.None);

       // Specify the input asset to be encoded.
       task.InputAssets.Add(asset);

       // Add an output asset to contain the results of the job.
       task.OutputAssets.AddNew("Output asset for encoding " + asset.Name + " using " + presetName, AssetCreationOptions.None);

       // Launch the job. 
       job.Submit();
   ```

Answer (score -1):

If i understood correctly you want to chain two task where input of second task is output of first task.
If so copy/pasting corresponding test from github repository
:https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-media-services/blob/dev/test/net/Scenario/JobTests.cs

```
[TestMethod]
            [DeploymentItem(@"Media\Thumbnail.xml", "Media")]
            [DeploymentItem(@"Media\SmallWmv.wmv", "Media")]
            [Priority(0)]
            [TestCategory("DailyBvtRun")]
            public void ShouldSubmitAndFinishChainedTasks()
            {
                IAsset asset = AssetTests.CreateAsset(_mediaContext, _smallWmv, AssetCreationOptions.StorageEncrypted);

                IJob job = _mediaContext.Jobs.Create("Test");
                IMediaProcessor mediaProcessor = GetMediaProcessor(_mediaContext, WindowsAzureMediaServicesTestConfiguration.MpEncoderName);
                ITask task = job.Tasks.AddNew("Task1", mediaProcessor, GetWamePreset(mediaProcessor), TaskOptions.None);
                task.InputAssets.Add(asset);
                IAsset asset2 = task.OutputAssets.AddNew("Another asset");

                string xmlPreset = File.ReadAllText(WindowsAzureMediaServicesTestConfiguration.ThumbnailXml);
                ITask task2 = job.Tasks.AddNew("Task2", mediaProcessor, xmlPreset, TaskOptions.None);
                task2.InputAssets.Add(asset2);
                task2.OutputAssets.AddNew("JobOutput", options: AssetCreationOptions.None);
                job.Submit();


                WaitForJob(job.Id, JobState.Finished, VerifyAllTasksFinished);
            }
```

Comment: This is not what I was asking for.